# Possible to only show first and last X rows in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible somehow to use shiny renderdatatable to only show the first and last row? Which is changed if the table is ordered.

For this example

```
if (interactive()) {
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
               dataTableOutput('table')
        )
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$table <- renderDataTable(data.frame(A = 1:20, B = 20:1),
                                      options = list(
                                        pageLength = 10
                                      )
      )
    }
  )
}
```

The desired output output would be

```
    A  B
1   1 20
20 20  1
```

and if the user orders by B instead

```
    A  B
1  20 1
20 1  20
```

Comment: Why not just do `df<-data.frame(A = 1:20, B = 20:1) df[c(1,nrow(df)),]` ?

Comment: As the original table has more than 2 columns, so that solution will not work.

Comment: Do you need the 1st and last row right? Why does column matter? The code basically allows you to display all columns, not 2 columns

Comment: Lets say you have a combination of data.frame(A = 1:20, B = 20:1, C = c(rep(1, 9), 20, 0, rep(1, 0)). If you only select first and last, then want to order by C, it will only have the values 1 as first and last, while it actually has 20 and 0 is the original df.

Comment: Could you add the ordering item to the original post to clarify how you want that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate your data table within a reactive space to create any behavior you want.  Here I take the head and tail of the df object after it has been ordered/reordered:

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(3,
               selectInput("ordering", "How to order", choices = c("A", "B"), selected = "A")),
        column(9,
               dataTableOutput('table')
        )
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$table <- renderDataTable({ 
        df <- data.frame(A = 1:20, B = 20:1)

        df <- df[order(df[[input$ordering]]), ]

        df_new <- rbind(head(df,1), tail(df,1))
        df_new
        },
        options = list(pageLength = 10))
    }
  )
}
```